# mapply error: 'length.out' must be a non-negative number

Tags: r, apply, mapply

I've created the following simple function:

```
fillampenv <- function(samples, samprate, rise, fall){
  # Create output vector
  v <- vector("numeric", samples)
  # Fill output vector
  v <- c(seq(0, 1, length = rise * samprate),
         seq(1, 1, length = (((samples/samprate) -
                                (rise + fall)) * samprate) -1),
         seq(1, 0, length = fall * samprate))
  return(v)
}
```

Which I'd like to call on each row of the dataframe:

```
df <- structure(list(samples = c(17640, 17640, 17640, 17640, 17640), samprate = c(44100, 44100, 44100, 44100, 44100), rise = c(0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75), fall = c(0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

However, when I tried to do this using the following (which works for me with other functions I've made):

```
ampenvs <- mapply(fillampenv,
                  samples = df$samples,
                  samprate = df$samprate,
                  rise = df$rise,
                  fall = df$fall)
```

I get the error:

```
Error in seq.default(1, 1, length = (((samples/samprate) - (rise + fall)) *  : 
  'length.out' must be a non-negative number
```

Any ideas why? I'm struggling to work out why it doesn't work with this function in particular (while others work just fine).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function results in negative `length.out` parameter passed to `seq`. For example,

```
> df %>% mutate(x = (((samples/samprate) -
+                       (rise + fall)) * samprate) -1)
  samples samprate rise fall      x
1   17640    44100 0.75  0.3 -28666
2   17640    44100 0.75  0.3 -28666
3   17640    44100 0.75  0.3 -28666
4   17640    44100 0.75  0.3 -28666
5   17640    44100 0.75  0.3 -28666
```

Answer (score 0):

Everywhere you faced this issue you have to parse your number to your desire one like Float, Integer and ...